# Split string into custom format

Tags: php, string, explode, implode

How can I split this string into a custom format?

input string:

```
14157.72,39140.94,36383.66,38508.00,8424.00
```

expected output:

```
['14157.72'],['39140.94'],['36383.66'],['38508.00'],['8424.00']
```

current code:

```
foreach($amount[0] as $aountlist){ 
    //$aountlist.= "'".$aountlist->HPIAmount.',';
    print_r($aountlist->HPIAmount);

    $defineamount = [$aountlist->HPIAmount];
}
```

How can I change my code to get the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with -

```
$string = '14157.72,39140.94,36383.66,38508.00,8424.00';
$temp = array();
$str = explode(',', $string);
foreach($str as $val){
   $temp[] = "[".$val."]";
}
echo implode(',', $temp);
```

Comment: `$temp` is completely unnecessary and you have a syntax error in your code

Comment: @QuestionUser Rizier123's answer is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

First [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your string by a comma, then simply [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it again.

```
$str = "14157.72,39140.94,36383.66,38508.00,8424.00";
echo "['" . implode("'],['", explode(",", $str)) . "']";
```

output:

```
['14157.72'],['39140.94'],['36383.66'],['38508.00'],['8424.00']
```

Comment: @sgtBOSE yeah, I think my solution is a bit before the border to get unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "14157.72,39140.94,36383.66,38508.00,8424.00"
$result = preg_replace('/([\d\.]+)/m', '[\'$1\']', $string );

echo $result;
```

Output:

```
['14157.72'],['39140.94'],['36383.66'],['38508.00'],['8424.00']
```

Comment: Also nice solution you just forgot the single question in the brackets :)

Comment: `$html` -> `$string`.

Comment: @Rizier123 always sharp :) tks